# How can I set my username in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, display-names

I am a new user and I'm using the Android app. How can I set my username? Is this possible at all from the app?

Comment: You get points through asking and answering questions. Not sure whether the Android app (which is fairly new) was designed with the *completely* new user in mind, though! Interesting.

Comment: That shouldn't happen - answering should be always possible. What message did it give you exactly? Can you quote it?

Comment: I've focused your question here on the username issue related to the Android app. If you have other support questions, bug reports or general discussions, please post them as separate questions. Make sure they haven't been discussed before though.

Comment: Please do not completely edit your question as it completely invalidates current answers. If you are happy with the answers you've got consider accepting it.

Comment: The question is not my question. It was changed by someone. Please delete it

Comment: @LeslieHewitt your original post had 3 topics: "How do i set my username?" (while stating you were using the Android App) "I can't comment without reputation" (which is a feature that's going to stay) and a rant about this being "the most unfriendly site for new users". A question should focus on 1 issue only, so I picked the most relevant Android one. If you feel the other topics still need to be discussed (and I'd recommend you to perhaps only constructively discuss issues you found as a new user) then ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Head over to your profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and click the "Edit Profile & Settings" link. From there you should be able to edit your username.

I don't believe profiles are editable (or even viewable) in the Android or iOS apps yet.